# Assuming that the speed of light slows down, will the physical phenomena also be slowed down?

Tags: speed-of-light, time

I rephrase a closed question.

In the context of Newtonian spacetime, and so assuming that the speed of light slows down relative to an moving object, will the physical phenomena of that object also be slowed down like a light clock?
I think so because physical phenomena evolve at the rate of energy exchanges taking place at the speed of light. If this speed slows down, the phenomena occur less quickly and therefore their duration increases. For example, if the speed of light slows down, people think slower and clocks run slower.

The closed question is here with calculations : [Is the slowing down of clocks foreseen by classical mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/728809/is-the-slowing-down-of-clocks-foreseen-by-classical-mechanics)

Comment: Unless $c$ is decreased by a large amount, clocks won't really run any slower. And for things in the same reference frame, there won't be any change in clock speed. Yes, people will think slower things like that, but it would be a measurable effect

Comment: Thanks, so this phenomenon is like time dilation? So there is no need for the Minkowski metric to explain time dilation ?

Comment: There is entirely a need for the Minkowski metric. I had a feeling you were going to try to push a personal theory. We don't measure people thinking slower but we do measure clocks running slower as well as a constant speed of light. If your theory suggests there is no measurable difference whatsoever from our theory, then go with the one that makes the fewest assumptions. That is, go with the "this is what we see, therefore it's that". If your theory makes predictions different from the established theory in the same circumstance, then think of a way to test for which predictions are observed

Comment: No time dilatation has nothing to do with increasing or decreasing of c,  but it depends on c.

Comment: Any question of the form "Assuming that [law of physics] changes, what will happen?" is unanswerable unless comprehensive details are provided regarding exactly how that change propagates out to the rest of the physical theories we have. Things tend to be *connected*, especially on a fundamental level, and abruptly changing one thing while leaving the rest unchanged introduces inconsistencies. For example: Is $c$ changing because the causal structure of spacetime is changing, or is this something which literally affects only the propagation speed of electromagnetic radiation?

Comment: To Jim : I have no personal theory. I want to know if the decrease in the speed of light affects the duration of physical processes. If light travels slower, it is logical to assume that all physical processes will be affected, since they rely on energy exchange taking place at the speed of light.

Comment: If the latter, is this because photons have gained some mass, or do we need to re-evaluate our understanding of how massless particles (or waves) pass through spacetime? If the latter, how does that understanding need to evolve?  Without answering questions of this type, asking how some other phenomena will change is presenting an question which could have a huge number of equally plausible answers.

Comment: To trula : I want explanations, not ready-made sentences.

Comment: To Murray : Well, put yourself in the context of non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics. The speed of light changes relative to an object because that object is moving relative to light. So will the physical processes of that object be slowed down ?

Comment: Non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics is an approximate model which is (by definition) ill-equipped for describing phenomena involving things moving near $c$. To what processes are you referring? Chemical reactions, the propagation of electrical signals, etc? The former involves quantum mechanics, the latter involves electrodynamics, both of which are outside the scope of Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: For example, the electrical impulses in the brain would be slowed down in the direction of movement and accelerated in the opposite direction, forcing the brain's phenomena to be desynchronised according to their spatial position. The round trip time of the electrical impulses would be slowed down by the factor gamma² in the direction of movement and by gamma in the orthogonal direction. I deduce all this without relativity, only with classical kinematics. And so on with all physical processes.

Comment: It sounds like you have already come up with an answer to your question, and are looking for a place to convince others that your answer and the associated models are better descriptions of nature than the ones we would consider to be mainstream. I fear that place is not here.

Comment: One could ask a million unmotivated questions of the form "In Newtonian mechanics, if X happened, would Y also happen?".   To have a chance of being on topic, you'd need to provide a reason why you think X and Y might be linked.  What in Newtonian mechanics links the speed of light to the speed of clocks?

Comment: To Murray : I ask a question and you don't know how to answer it, that's all.
And even if the answer should be positive, it remains in mainstream physics because it is compatible with Lorentz's aether theory which is equivalent to Einstein's relativity

Comment: To WillO : How does a clock work? By exchanges of energy at the atomic level, and if these exchanges slow down the clock will run slower.

Comment: @externo:  What in Newtonian mechanics makes you think that exchanges of energy must be mediated by light?   Newtonian mechanics models the motion of colliding billiard balls without even mentioning the *existence* of light.  (It also doesn't mention "the atomic level".)

Comment: It's current physics that makes me think so, not Newton's mechanics. I don't place myself in Newtonian mechanics but I place myself in Newtonian space-time and not in Minkowski's space-time. In fact, I place myself within the framework of Lorentz's theory.

Comment: In what system of measurement do you propose that the speed of light changes? In the SI, $c$ is defined to be constant, so it cannot be different. What definitions of time and distance, and what experiment do you propose to use them to measure $c$?

Comment: Measured in a resting frame the speed of light changes relative to a moving object. If this object moves at speed v the light propagating in the direction of the object will have a relative speed of c - v with respect to the object.

Answer (score 1):

> In the context of non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics, assuming that the speed of light slows down relative to an moving object, will the physical phenomena of that object also be slowed down?

No. In non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics the speed of light does not determine the rate of physical phenomena. For example, there is nothing in non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics which limits the speed of sound to less than the speed of light, e.g. for a Newtonian rigid object with infinite speed of sound. Nor is there anything that connects the speed of light to the functioning of mechanical devices like mechanical watches. Nor is there anything that connects the speed of light to gravity. In non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics the speed of light has no more significance than the speed of sound.

Instead, from the laws of non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics one can easily derive the Galilean transform. Moving clocks do not slow down under the Galilean transform. So quite the opposite can be shown.

As a side note: "assuming that the speed of light slows down relative to an moving object" is very vague in any case. How much does it slow down? In what sense is the object moving? How are you defining velocities relative to that object?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You write : "For example, there is nothing in non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics which limits the speed of sound to less than the speed of light, e.g. for a Newtonian rigid object with infinite speed of sound."

If we assume that the kinetic energy of an object is stored in its mass, the object becomes more and more difficult to accelerate as the mass increases and the speed tends towards the c limit naturally due to the relation E = mc²
Newtonian mechanics just lacks the knowledge that kinetic energy increases mass.

Comment: You wrote : "Nor is there anything that connects the speed of light to the functioning of mechanical devices like mechanical watches."
If the clock moves its mass increases, it takes more energy to make it go at the same speed and it is logical to think that if the same energy is supplied to it, the mechanism will slow down.

Comment: $E=mc^2$ cannot be obtained from non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics, so that would be "cheating" to introduce without an explicit assumption. However, it is irrelevant anyway. The speed of sound in a Newtonian rigid object is infinite, even when every part of the object has negligible velocity. An infinite speed of sound does not imply that any matter is moving fast, merely that the object does not deform while moving at arbitrarily low speeds.

Comment: You wrote : "Instead, from the laws of non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics one can easily derive the Galilean transform. Moving clocks do not slow down under the Galilean transform. So quite the opposite can be shown." The Galilean transform is only a mathematical formula and it becomes false when it is assumed that the clocks are slowing down since it does not take into account this slowing down.

Comment: E = mc² can be obtained by Lorentz's theory as well as by relativity. The mathematics of the two theories are the same. About the speed of sound I admit I don't quite understand the issue.

Comment: You wrote "As a side note: "assuming that the speed of light slows down relative to an moving object" is very vague in any case. How much does it slow down? In what sense is the object moving? How are you defining velocities relative to that object?" The calculations are given in the closed question. These are the equations of a light clock. The round trip of the light is slowed down by a factor gamma² in the direction of movement and gamma in the orthogonal direction. With the additional assumption of the contraction the slowing down is of gamma in every direction. It's simply relativity.

Comment: Lorentz's theory is also not part of non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics. You cannot say "non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics" and then try to sneak in $E=mc^2$, Lorentz aether theory, length contraction, or anything else. If you want to assume those other things then you need to state them as assumptions, not merely "non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics". They do not follow from that

Comment: Ok, I have changed the text. I place myself in newtonian spacetime, that is to say within Lorentz' interpretation of relativity.

Comment: The question has been closed again, I really think I hit the nail on the head. If this is the scientific community, it's a bunch of jokers...

Comment: It isn't the community's fault that you do not clearly state your assumptions. If you assume only "non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics" then you cannot bring in length contraction, $E=mc^2$, or anything else from relativity whether Einstein's version or Lorentz's version. Your claim that you can derive relativity from "non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics" only is simply wrong as shown. You must include some additional assumptions. What you need to do is to take a bit of time and figure out what additional assumptions you accept, and then build a solid careful argument from clear assumptions

Comment: Ok, I will think about a third version.

Comment: If you are interested in this problem, you can discover in this paper that relativity and quantum physics are not the true physical reality. Matter is made of waves is the reality that explains everything. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.4356.pdf and Lorentz interpretation is the true one. Look at this also : https://www.quora.com/According-to-the-special-theory-of-relativity-the-length-contracts-How-does-this-happen/answer/Rudolph-Jensen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139399/discussion-between-externo-and-dale).